# PySpark Row objects: accessing row elements by variable names

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

One can access PySpark `Row` elements using the dot notation: given `r= Row(name="Alice", age=11)`, one can get the name or the age using `r.name` or `r.age` respectively. What happens when one needs to get an element whose name is stored in a variable `element`? One option is to do `r.toDict()[element]`. However, consider a situation where we have a large `DataFrame` and we wish to map a function on each row of that data frame. We can certainly do something like

```
def f(row, element1, element2):
    row = row.asDict()
    return ", ".join(str(row[element1]), str(row[element2]))

result = dataframe.map(lambda row: f(row, 'age', 'name'))
```

However, it seems that calling `toDict()` on every row will be very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: > Maybe a `filter`
Can you show an example, I can't figure out how to use `filter` for this.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, however the second part of my small explanation is correct. A `map` is one of the fastest jobs because it is easy to parallelize.

Comment: I know that `map` is good. I would like to make it better but not having to convert every row to a dict

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I would like to make it better **BY** not having to convert every row to a dict

Answer (score 7):

As always in Python if something works there is no magic there. When something works, like dot syntax here, it means a predictable chain of events. In particular you can expect that `__getattr__` method will be called:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

a_row = Row(foo=1, bar=True)

a_row.__getattr__("foo")
## 1
a_row.__getattr__("bar")
True
```

Row also overrides `__getitem__` to have the same behavior:

```
a_row.__getitem__("foo")
## 1
```

It means you can use bracket notation:

```
a_row["bar"]
## True
```

Problem is that it is not efficient. Each call is *O(N)* so a single conversion to `dict` can be more efficient if you have wide rows and multiple calls.

In general you should avoid calls like this:

- using UDF is as inefficient but much cleaner in general
- using built-in SQL expressions should be preferred over `map`
- you shouldn't map directly over `DataFrame`. Its gonna be deprecated soon.

Comment: > Each call is O(N)

Is N the number of columns? In my case this is pretty small and I suspect that memory allocation/garbage collection that accompanies `.asDict()` would take more time. I guess I just have to measure the timings. Thank you

Comment: The funny thing is that the day before I asked this question, I wrote a bunch of wrappers and implemented several `__getattr__` and `__getitem__` functions. Then I switched the context and forgot about them :-)

Comment: You're probably right about it although I would avoid Python mappers in Spark SQL, and if you use this extract values explicitly before you execute mapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
python_var_list =[ [ele[0],ele[1]] for ele in r]
```

The above line of code in should access the row elements in pyspark for every row in r

Comment: hey Rajesh, welcome to stackoverflow. I put your code in a code block using crtl K (while the code is selected). Its really useful and helps other users to read & copy your solution.